# Shortest polygonal line that connects three disjointing circles

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

Given three disjointing circles, how to find the shortest polygonal line (consisting of two line segments) that connects the three circles (a line segment connects circle *A* and *B* if it starts with some point on *A* and ends with some point on *B*)

Comment: Why not just evaluate the three segments through the centers (subtract the radiuses) and pick the two shortest of the three?

Comment: by polygonal line, it implies that the two line segments should share an end point

Comment: Circles or disks ? Can the segments penetrate inside the circles ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortest polygonal path $\gamma=\gamma_{ABC}$ from disk $A$ to disk $B$ to disk $C$ is found as follows: If the segment $[m_A,m_C]$ connecting the midpoints of $A$ and $C$ hits the disk $B$ then $\gamma$ is part of this segment. Otherwise $\gamma$ is lying on two lines $\ell_A$ and $\ell_C$ through  $m_A$ and $m_C$. These lines intersect at a point $P$ on the circle $\partial B$, whereby the following condition is satisfied:

$(*)$ The line $\ell_B:=m_B\vee P$ is an angle bisector of the lines $\ell_A$,  $\ell_C$ intersecting at $P$.

*Reason for* $(*)$: The shortest path from $m_A$ to $B$ to $m_C$ (that's what we need) is found as follows: Find the ellipse $\epsilon$ with foci $m_A$ and $m_C$ that touches $B$ at a point $P\in\partial B$. Then $\epsilon$ and $\partial B$ have a common tangent at $P$, and the rays $[m_A,P]$, $[P,m_C]$ are reflected on this tangent.

Unfortunately this leads to complicated equations for the angles involved.

One would have to solve the above problem for all three tours $A\to B\to C$, $\ B\to C\to A$, $C\to A\to B$ separately and then take the shortest of the three tours so obtained.

Comment: very insightful ans. By "Unfortunately this leads to complicated equations for the angles involved", do you already solve the equation or you know some solved problem similar to this? Otherwise how do you know $\gamma_{ABC}$ is the shortest?

Comment: You mean at the beginning that $\gamma$ is the segment and same goes for other option of intersection.